# Can you throw a teammate in the brig to get them aboard the ship faster?

Tags: sea-of-thieves

I'm watching some streamers/youtubers play Sea of Thieves, and I'm wondering something:

If a team mate falls off the ship, or is far away on an island; could you vote him into the brig then vote him out to teleport him to the ship (instead of waiting for him to make his way to the ship)?

Would voting a player of the crew into the brig teleport him aboard, or are there limitations to the vote into the brig system that would prevent this from working?

Comment: I'm curious if this will work actually.  When a teammate falls off the boat, a mermaid appears in the water near them that will take them back to the boat after the boat travels too far away.  I assume the same will happen if they are on land and the boat moves too far away.  But I suppose if you vote fast enough, it could be a faster means of getting your teammate back.

Comment: The minimum sentence time prevents this from being useful in most cases, but it is still useful if your teammate gets stuck in the terrain and cannot move, as it's the only way (besides leaving the game) to get them out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would work in theory, but there is a minimum amount of time a crew member must be in the brig before they can be removed.

While I'm not certain on the length of time required (best guess is 2-3 minutes), my experience is that the mermaid/merman appears sooner than the brig timer expires.

Comment: So yes you could, but it's better to just wait for the mermaid because if you throw somebody in the brig to teleport them aboard, they will be stuck in it for 2-3 minutes